# How to add two binary number converted from decimal

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, type-conversion

I have written a program here where two decimal numbers are converted to binary. I want to add the two binary and store them in separate memory??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
int main ()
    {
        int arr[10],a,b,i;
        cout<<"Enter First Integer(must be last 2 digit of arid number) : ";
        cin>>a;
        for(i=0;a>0;i++)
        {
        arr[i]=a % 2;
        a /= 2; 
        }
        cout<<"First Binary Conversion : ";
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
        cout << arr[j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Second Integer(any number between 1-100) : ";
        cin>>b;
        for(i=0;b>0;i++)
        {
        arr[i]=b % 2;
        b /= 2;     
        }
        cout<<"Second Binary Conversion : ";
        for (int k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) 
        {
        cout << arr[k];
        }
        
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: First you need to have two different locations for your two numbers. If you overwrite first number with second then you obviously can not add them up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you restructure your code significantly. This is what I produced so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;

class Decimal {
public:
    short   array[16];
    int     mostSignificant {0};

    Decimal() {}

    Decimal(unsigned int value) {
        int index = 0;
        while (value != 0) {
            array[index++] = value % 2;
            value = value / 2;
        }
        mostSignificant = index - 1;
    }

    Decimal operator+(const Decimal &value) const {
        Decimal retVal { 0 };

        // This is the tricky part, as it's cheating to use math to implement this.
        return retVal;
    };
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream &ostr, const Decimal &value) {
    for (int index = value.mostSignificant; index >= 0; --index) {
        ostr << value.array[index];
    }
    return ostr;
}



int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " 99 75 " << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    Decimal first{ static_cast<unsigned int>(atoi(argv[1])) };
    Decimal second{ static_cast<unsigned int>(atoi(argv[2])) };

    std::cout << "First : " << first << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Second: " << second << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
g++ Decimal.cpp -o Decimal  && Decimal 2 7
First : 10
Second: 111
```

Basically, I defined a class for storing the binary representation of your numbers and initialized from the command line. You could initialize your way instead. But this gives you a distinct place to put it without reproducing your code repeatedly. It's nice and clean.

This only leaves the addition method, which is the operator+ function inside class Decimal(). You haven't made an attempt at that part yet, and I didn't want to do your homework for you.

But in short, you have to produce output into the retVal that adds array[] and value.array[]. And I think this is probably the main thrust of your entire assignment, so you should give it a try and ask specific questions.